# Defining arithmetic operators that insert brackets according to usual precedence rules

Tags: macros, math-operators

I have a program that generates bits of Tex code like these:

```
$\product{a}{\add{b}{c}}\leftrightarrow \add{\product{a}{b}}{\product{a}{c}}$
$\add{a}{\add{b}{c}}\leftrightarrow \add{\add{a}{b}}{c}$
$\product{a}{b}\leftrightarrow \product{b}{a}$
$\product{a}{\product{b}{c}}\leftrightarrow \product{\product{a}{b}}{c}$
$\subtract{\power{x}{\two}}{\power{y}{\two}}\leftrightarrow \product{\add{x}{y}}{\subtract{x}{y}}$
```

At the moment, I have defined

```
\newcommand\add[2]{({#1}+{#2})}
\newcommand\subtract[2]{({#1}-{#2})}
\newcommand\product[2]{({#1}{#2})}
```

But this results in far too many brackets being produced -- for example `\sum{\product{a}{b}}{c}` is rendered as *((ab)+c)*.

**How can I define `\add`, `\product` and other arithmetic operations so that the minimum number of necessary brackets are added?**  Just to clarify, I want `\product{a}{\add{b}{c}}`  to generate *a(b+c)*, but `\sum{\product{a}{b}}{c}`  to produce *ab + c*.

NB. If it was straightforward to do this in the code that generated the TeX, I would be doing so!

Comment: From prefix form to infix form with the usual conventions about precedence? I surely wouldn't undertake the task. `;-)`

Comment: I've done it in C++ in the past. (Currently using Haskell, where the key problem is that `sum`, etc. are stored purely as data.) At heart, this is a rendering issue and it would be very nice if it could be solved once and for all in a rendering language. But I have no idea how to start with the tools available in TeX...

Comment: David Carlisle came up with an absolutely brilliant solution, but jfbu's tweak to it is in technical terms a clear improvement. Which should I accept?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Probably I don't have the precedence rules exactly as you need, but something like

[image]

```
\def\p{0}

\def\power#1#2{%
\ifnum\p>20(\fi
{\def\p{20}#1}^{\def\p{0}#2}%
\ifnum\p>20)\fi}

\def\product#1#2{%
\ifnum\p>20(\fi
{\def\p{20}#1#2}%
\ifnum\p>20)\fi}

\def\add#1#2{%
\ifnum\p>10(\fi
{\def\p{10}#1+#2}%
\ifnum\p>10)\fi}

\def\subtract#1#2{%
\ifnum\p>8(\fi
{\def\p{9}#1-#2}%
\ifnum\p>8)\fi}


\def\two{2}

$\product{a}{\add{b}{c}}\leftrightarrow \add{\product{a}{b}}{\product{a}{c}}$

$\add{a}{\add{b}{c}}\leftrightarrow \add{\add{a}{b}}{c}$

$\product{a}{b}\leftrightarrow \product{b}{a}$

$\product{a}{\product{b}{c}}\leftrightarrow \product{\product{a}{b}}{c}$

$\subtract{\power{x}{\two}}{\power{y}{\two}}\leftrightarrow \product{\add{x}{y}}{\subtract{x}{y}}$

$\subtract{a}{\subtract{b}{c}}$

$\subtract{\subtract{a}{b}}{c}$


\bye
```

Comment: Magnificent!!!!

Comment: @Mohan I just updated to fix a-b-c

Comment: `$\subtract{\subtract{\subtract{a}{b}}{c}}{d}$` generates `((a − b) − c) − d` but the minimal representation would be `a-b-c-d`.

Comment: and `$\add{a}{\subtract{b}{c}}$` generates `a + (b -c)` where `a + b - c` is the minimal representation.

Comment: @jfbu yes I played safe, making precedence of - a bit lower than + you can make them equal and make the precedence of the first argument of - be 10 as well, if you wish

Answer (score 9):

This answer is initially motivated from [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161378/4686). But to address the issues I raised in the comments a different perspective is needed.

I have not thoroughly tested the code does in all circumstances what is hoped for. The aim is to use as few parentheses as possible.

Update: the sentence about a *different perspective* is not quite exact. I started with a different perspective but in the end, looking at the result a bit later, I see that the code is only a slight evolution of [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161378/4686). I have thus rewritten it in a style closer to that answer.

```
\def\p{0}

\def\power #1#2{% 
   \ifnum\p>3(\fi
     {\def\p{4}#1}^{\def\p{0}#2}%
   \ifnum\p>3)\fi
}

\def\product #1#2{% 
  \ifnum\p>2(\fi
   {\def\p{2}#1#2}% perhaps #1\cdot #2 would be better
  \ifnum\p>2)\fi
}

\def\add #1#2{%
  \ifnum\p>1(\fi
    {\def\p{0}#1+#2}%
  \ifnum\p>1)\fi
}

\def\subtract #1#2{%
  \ifnum\p>0(\fi
     {\def\p{0}#1-\def\p{2}#2}%
  \ifnum\p>0)\fi
}

\def\two{2}

$\product{a}{\add{b}{c}}\leftrightarrow \add{\product{a}{b}}{\product{a}{c}}$

$\add{a}{\product{b}{c}}$

$\add{a}{\product{b}{\subtract{c}{d}}}$

$\add{a}{\add{b}{c}}\leftrightarrow \add{\add{a}{b}}{c}$

$\product{a}{b}\leftrightarrow \product{b}{a}$

$\product{a}{\product{b}{c}}\leftrightarrow \product{\product{a}{b}}{c}$

$\subtract{\power{x}{\two}}{\power{y}{\two}}\leftrightarrow \product{\add{x}{y}}{\subtract{x}{y}}$

$\subtract{a}{\subtract{b}{c}}$

$\subtract{\subtract{a}{b}}{c}$

$\product{a}{\add{b}{c}}$ 

$\add{\product{a}{b}}{c}$


$\subtract{a}{\subtract{b}{\subtract{c}{d}}}$

$\subtract{\subtract{\subtract{a}{b}}{c}}{d}$

$\add{a}{\subtract{b}{c}}$

$\subtract{\add{a}{b}}{\add{c}{d}}$

$\add{\subtract{\add{a}{b}}{\add{c}{d}}}{\add{e}{f}}$

$\power{x}{\power{y}{z}}$

$\power{\power{x}{y}}{z}$

$\power{x}{\add{y}{z}}$

$\power{x}{\power{y}{\add{z}{w}}}$

$\subtract{\power{x}{\product{\power{y}{\add{z}{w}}}{\subtract{z}{w}}}}{\subtract{d}{e}}$

\nopagenumbers
\bye
```

How I wrote it first: (I had something more general in mind for the branch contents, but in the end they differ only in the presence of `(` and `)`)

```
\catcode`@ 11
\long\def\@firstoftwo #1#2{#1}
\long\def\@secondoftwo #1#2{#2}

\def\power #1#2{% 
\ifnum\p>3 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{{({\def\p{4}#1}^{\def\p{0}#2})}}{{\def\p{4}#1}^{\def\p{0}#2}}}

\def\product#1#2{% 
\ifnum\p>2 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{{(\def\p{2}#1#2)}}{{\def\p{2}#1#2}}}

\def\add#1#2{%
\ifnum\p>1 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{{(\def\p{0}#1+#2)}}{{\def\p{0}#1+#2}}}

\def\subtract#1#2{%
\ifnum\p>0 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{{(\def\p{0}#1-\def\p{2}#2)}}{{\def\p{0}#1-\def\p{2}#2}}}

\catcode`@ 12
```

[image: parentheses removal]

Comment: Am I right in thinking the only change from David Carlisle's answer is that the numerical parameters have been changed?

Comment: it's a bit more for `\subtract` (`\p` is changed at two locations and goes up to multiplication in a way) and also `\power` (the first `\p` changes in the opposite direction). As a result `(((a-b)-c)-d)` and `a+(b-c)` are correctly stripped of parentheses.

Comment: and `$\power{\power{\power{x}{y}}{z}}{t}$` is correctly handled to output `((x^y)^z)^t`.